# How to limit number of copies of a sheet?

Tags: vba

I am looking to update the below code and limit the number of times the Template is copied and renamed based on the input in the Input tab. There should be only 2 copies and if someone tries to create a 3rd one a message to pop saying something like "You can only create 2 tabs". The existing code is the following:

I am a beginner so got some help on some parts of this code and not sure how to proceed with this further

```
Sub scorecard()

    Dim A, B As String
    Dim lgn, col As Integer

    A = ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 5).Value & "_" & ActiveSheet.Cells(9, 5).Value
    B = ActiveSheet.Name

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets(A).Select

    If ActiveSheet.Name = A Then
        Sheets(B).Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox ("This name already exists")
    Else

        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = A
```

Comment: Just a note, try to [avoid declaring variables on one line](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Style-Guide#no-one-line-declarations). Both `A` and `lgn` are declared as `Variants` the way you have it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent a user from creating a certain number of sheets with the same name then you would want to use the [Workbook events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook).

I would think `SheetActivate` should do the trick.

The easiest way to implement this would be to work within your project under the `ThisWorkbook` which can be found in the Microsoft Excel Objects folder.

[image: Microsoft Excel Objects Folder]

From here you can use select the `Workbook` object in the left dropdown and then select the `SheetActivate` event in the right dropdown.

[image]

---

Every time this event occurs we would want to call a function to check if the name matches and if it has more than your max limit, in your case 2.

Here is the event, and we want to pass the `Sh` reference to our function.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    LimitNumberOfMatchingSheets Sh
End Sub
```

Here is the function we create that checks for the matching name and the max.

If it does meet those criteria then you could simply give the user your message and delete the newly created (or copied) worksheet.

```
Private Sub LimitNumberOfMatchingSheets(ByRef sheet As Worksheet)

    Const sheetName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const maxLimit As Long = 2

    'If name matches and max is reached then delete new worksheet
    If InStr(sheet.Name, sheetName) > 0 _
            And MatchingSheetNameCount(sheetName, ThisWorkbook) > maxLimit Then

        'I would put a better description here.
        MsgBox "This name already exists"

        'Disable the users ability to cancel the deletion.
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        sheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End Sub
```

One last helper function that checks for the count of matching sheet names.

```
Private Function MatchingSheetNameCount(ByVal likeName As String, ByVal book As Workbook) As Long

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    For Each sheet In book.Worksheets
        If InStr(sheet.Name, likeName) > 0 Then
            MatchingSheetNameCount = MatchingSheetNameCount + 1
        End If
    Next sheet

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Robert. However the sheets that will be create will all have different names. So in nutshell there is template tab and an input tab. In the input the user specifies the name then a copy is created of Template tab and renamed based on what was provided in the Input tab. Then this is repeated with a new name. So what I want is them to not be able to do this more than 2 times.